# The use the adjective "free" in context

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, phrase-choice

Let's say it is the end of a class and the teacher wants to dismiss the students. Is natural to say *you are free*? Would it be more natural to say *you can go*? Anyway what would a native English teacher say?

Comment: Whenever I read your questions and see *"What would a **native** ..."*, I feel as if I shouldn't be contributing. Do you feel that way too? (Please note this is not me "picking up a fight", as it were, but rather just me truly wanting to know if you'd rather only native English speakers to answer)

Comment: I am happy to have anwers from native and non-native speakers provided they are natural sounding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always said, instead,

> That's it, guys! Have a nice day.

and variations. **Personally**, *you are free* doesn't sound as good, and *you can go (now)* sounds a bit rude, but that's just me. Both your examples are good and correct; it depends on context.

Comment: Since everyone knows that the students can leave when the class is over, the teacher doesn't need to spell it out. Like you, they probably just say something to indicate that they have finished teaching, such as "That's all for today," or "I'll see you next week".